# Limit of $\lim_{x\to 0-} x^4e^{-1/x}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

How can I calculate the limit of $\lim_{x\to 0-} x^4e^{-1/x}$

I tried using de l'Hospital but couldn't get and further because I always get undefined expressions.
Thank you!

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0^-}x^4e^{\frac{-1}{x}}&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{x^{-4}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{-4x^{-5}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{-4x^{-3}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{12x^{-4}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{12x^{-2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{-24x^{-3}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{-24x^{-1}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{24x^{-2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{24}\\
&=\infty
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Set $-1/x=h$

to find $$\lim_{x\to0^-}x^4e^{-1/x}=\lim_{h\to\infty^+}\dfrac{e^h}{h^4}$$

Now apply [L'Hôpital's Rule](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lhopitals-rule/#lhopitals-rule-medium)

Comment: Isn't the latter  form a basic high school limit?

Comment: @Bernard, Yes when one knows about http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html of $e^h$

Comment: $\mathrm e^h/h\to 0$ when $\to+\infty$ is in the curriculum of high school here, and the other cases are seen as standard exercises.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y:=-1/x$ and consider $y \rightarrow +\infty$, i.e.

$\lim_{y \rightarrow + \infty} \dfrac{e^y}{y^4}.$

$e^y \gt $

$1+y+y^2/2! +.....+ y^5/5! $

The limit is?

Comment: Nice argument Peter!

Answer (score 1):

Note that by ratio test

$$a_n=\frac{e^n}{n^4}\implies\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e\cdot\left(1+\frac1n\right)^4\to e\implies a_n \to +\infty$$

Comment: Gimusi. In 2 lines! Formidable!

Comment: I would used your method but you did it first! it is just to give an alternative way to see it and to prove.